# How to generate SQL script pragmatically in c#

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, c#-4.0

I want to generate txt/sql file using c# code which will have "insert script" for all the table data available in database.
E.g. My database name is "Test". It has two tables

1. Employee
2. Department.

**Department data:**

**ID**  **Name**
1   Account

**Employee data**

**ID**  **Name** **DeptD**
   1      Ravi       1      
   6      Ripal      1

**Now my c# code should generate txt/sql file with following content.**

```
USE [Test]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Department] ON 

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Department] ([ID], [Name]) VALUES (1, N'Account')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Department] OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ON 

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([ID], [Name],  [DeptID]) VALUES (1, N'Ravi', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([ID], [Name],  [DeptID]) VALUES (6, N'Ripal', 1)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Employee] OFF
GO
```

Comment: From what ?? Please state your  requirement clearly and with all inputs and the code to implemented.

Comment: SSMS allows you to do this: Right-click on the database then Tasks->Generate Scripts. It will open a pop-up window.

Comment: @coder of Code: I have updated my requirement.

Comment: @Alex:  I want to do this grammatically.

Comment: I have created one procedure which is mentioned in answer that is generating insert script  if you you would like to modify according to your situation then you cab. Check it

Answer (score 2):

You can create procedure for this and call that procedure from C#

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_generate_insertscripts
(
    @TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(MAX),
    @FILTER_CONDITION VARCHAR(MAX)=''
)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @CSV_COLUMN VARCHAR(MAX),
        @QUOTED_DATA VARCHAR(MAX),
        @TEXT VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @CSV_COLUMN=STUFF
(
    (
     SELECT ',['+ NAME +']' FROM sys.all_columns 
     WHERE OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID(@TABLE_NAME) AND 
     is_identity!=1 FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,''
)

SELECT @QUOTED_DATA=STUFF
(
    (
     SELECT ' ISNULL(QUOTENAME('+NAME+','+QUOTENAME('''','''''')+'),'+'''NULL'''+')+'','''+'+' FROM sys.all_columns 
     WHERE OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID(@TABLE_NAME) AND 
     is_identity!=1 FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,''
)

SELECT @TEXT='SELECT ''INSERT INTO '+@TABLE_NAME+'('+@CSV_COLUMN+')VALUES('''+'+'+SUBSTRING(@QUOTED_DATA,1,LEN(@QUOTED_DATA)-5)+'+'+''')'''+' Insert_Scripts FROM '+@TABLE_NAME + @FILTER_CONDITION

--SELECT @CSV_COLUMN AS CSV_COLUMN,@QUOTED_DATA AS QUOTED_DATA,@TEXT TEXT

EXECUTE (@TEXT)

SET NOCOUNT OFF

END

--EXEC sp_generate_insertscripts 'tableName'
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the database has export functionality that you can use to generate INSERT script to transfer the data into another database but it differs from database to database.